# How to open a Jung Frame class using JBUtton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jung2

I have created a class called "Display"and one JFrame class called"SimpleGraphicView" which uses jung2. I am trying to create a button that opens the JFrame.
I have tried the following code

```
JButton btnInteractions = new JButton("DNetwork");
    btnInteractions.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString()
                    .equals("Hereditery Breast Cancer")) {
                SimpleGraphicView frame = new SimpleGraphicView();
                frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                frame.setSize(600, 600);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.getContentPane();
            }
```

In the JUung Frame Class

```
public void run() {
            try {
                SimpleGraphicView frame = new SimpleGraphicView();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.getContentPane().***add(vv);***
                frame.pack();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

But the content in Jung2 Frame is not displaying. How can I do this???

Comment: What's the relationship between the top code and the bottom code?

Comment: First one is from the class which i want to display second the frame using Jbutton. The second is from Jung JFrame class.(The frame to be display)

Comment: What's vv? That appears to be what you want, not SimpleGraphView

Comment: vv  is a VisualizationViewer in jung class

Comment: That's my point, I think you want to create an instance of VisulaizationViewer to your frame and not SimpleGraphicViewer